# View pager is taking time to load pages

Tags: android, android-viewpager, singleton

I have an Activity with ListView and ViewPager below it. Initially my ViewPager is not visible and becomes visible after clicking a toggle button. The ViewPager contains 4 tabs. 1st tab contains ListView of texts, 2nd tab contains all the music/mp3 inside the phone, 3rd tab shows all the images inside phone and the 4th tab shows all the videos inside the phone.
 I have setOffscreenPageLimit(3) to avoid views being created again and again.

To avoid fetching data for the tabs again and again, I used singleton classes.

Below is the class which gives me texts

```
public class TextManager {

private static ArrayList<String> text = new ArrayList<>();
private static TextManager instance;

public static TextManager getInstance() {
    if(instance == null) {
        instance = new TextManager();
    }
    return instance;
}

public TextManager() {
    // get all the texts here
}

public ArrayList<String> getText() {
    return text;
}
}
```

Same is the class for Music, Images and Video. Only difference is in the constructor to get the data from phone.

When my activity is visible, the ViewPager is not visible. ViewPager's visibility is controlled by a toggle button. I clicked on the toggle button, now the ViewPager becomes visible. The first time ViewPager becomes visible it makes 1-2 seconds. However once its visible if I hide and show the ViewPager again and again, it hides and becomes visible instantaneously, which is not the case for first time.

If I go back to previous Activity and comes on this activity, still it takes time for first time and becomes visible fast for the rest of time.

I want the view to be instantaneously visible even for the first time. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Like if You have ParentFragment inside this 4 fragments like Frag1, Frag2, Frag3, Frag4

So, in

```
Frag1.java extends Fragment
{
    onCreate()
    {
        inflate layout...
    }
    onStart()
    {
        new Handler().postdelay(new Runnable() { //same thing for other Fragments
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //all your code will go here
            }
        }
        ,0);
    }
}
```

Similarly do the same thing for all other three fragments but be sure that in onResume() there should not be any code dependent on onStart(). and all your code should be in Handler() so that all four fragments can execute parallel.